# load extended controller from CI spark

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter spark defining&autoloading a class `libraries/Nci_nicecontroller.php`:

```
class Nci_nicecontroller extends CI_Controller {
  //...
}
//autoloaded using $autoload['libraries'][]='nci_nicecontroller';
```

now I want to use `Nci_nicecontroller` in my application's controller, e.g.:

```
class Welcome extends Nci_nicecontroller {
  //...
}
//autoloaded using $autoload['sparks'][]='nci-extensions/0.0.4';
```

obviously, I can't just `$this->load->spark` in my controller's constructor, because it's required on class extension.

when not using sparks, I just put the Nci_nicecontroller in a `core/MY_Controller.php`, but with sparks, this won't work.

I tried autoloading the spark in my application, which didn't work.

Then I tried:

```
get_instance()->load->spark('nci-extensions/0.0.4');
```

in the header of `controllers/welcome.php`, which gives me following errors:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: controllers/welcome.php
Line Number: 2
    --and--
Fatal error: Call to a member function spark() on a non-object in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_demo\application\controllers\welcome.php on line 2
```

what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like that:

```
class Wellcome extends CI_Controller {
  protected static $_nci = null;

  public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->_nci = $this->load->spark('nci-extensions/0.0.4');
  }

  public function index(){
      $result = $this->_nci->getSomething();
      echo $result;
  }

}
```

Comment: that would show me if my spark is being loaded at all, but doesn't address my problem (loading the spark before my controller is instanciated, so the controller can be defined as "extends NCI..."), or am I missing something?

Comment: if you need to load your spark before controller starts, you can use autoloading. Just add to application/config/autoload.php next string: $autoload['sparks'] = array('nci-extensions/0.0.4');  After that you spark will be available as $this->nci_extensions->do_something();

Comment: I tried that before, won't work, as the whole Loader class is instanciated in CI_Controller for the first time. a quick and dirty hack is: `$load =& load_class('Loader', 'core'); @$load->initialize();` in the header of my controller.